# Use all google maps API features in AngularJS

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am working on a project relying on AngularJS where I need to locate all airports in the world and link them with lines.

To do so, I searched for some existing projects that set angular directives to embed Google Maps API into my project: Namely `Angular-ui-map` (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map), `Angular-google-maps` (https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps) and `AngularGM` (https://github.com/dylanfprice/angular-gm)

But the problem is that none of those projects talks about Google Maps Polylines !

Anyone has already been able to use the complete set of Google Maps features ? Or I should create my own directives to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This might be easier to implement with d3 and angularjs.  Check out this example that is for US airports.  http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The example is interesting but I am looking for the same thing on a Map (not necessarily a google maps ). I conclude also from what you've said that Google Maps API's polylines are not supported (yet?) in AngularJS...

Comment: Are you able to implement something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/E45Su/light/) into an AngularJS controller or directive?

Answer (score 0):

I've used another project called [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) which claims to

> Expose all original Google Maps V3 api to the user.

Indeed it does provide a directive for polylines (example from documentation, works for me):

```
<map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]">
    <shape id="polyline" name="polyline" geodesic="true"
           stroke-color="#FF0000" stroke-opacity="1.0" stroke-weight="2"
           path="[[40.74,-74.18],[40.64,-74.10],[40.54,-74.05],[40.44,-74]]" ></shape>
</map>
```